# Routing Engine written in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, software-recommendations, routing, node-js, vehicle-routing-problem

I'm looking for a **routing engine** written completely in native **JavaScript** or **Nodejs**, which is distributed with an open source license
So far the solutions I've found are implemented only in Java, C++ or Python.

Comment: I can't be sure, but does GraphHopper meet those criteria?

Comment: GraphHopper is written in Java

Comment: Not a routing engine in a narrower sense, but there is a JS port of NetworkX (originally written in Python): [JSNetworkX](http://jsnetworkx.org)

Comment: I don't see the routing features in this library